# Refresh table data whenever sqlite updates

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, sqlite, apple-push-notifications

I am using the push notifications in my app. I am getting some data from the server through the push notifications.

I am saving that data in sqlite. I would like to show that data in table view in another class. Actually my problem is here, when i am getting the new data from the server that will automatically stores in to the database.

So when the sqlite updates i would like to show refresh data in table view from sqlite database. Refreshing the table continuously when the sqlite updates.

Comment: now what the problem u faced, refresh is the problem

Comment: if you want to update a tableview when sqlite update then used notification.
Fire notification every time when any data update in sqlite

Comment: after sqlite update use postNotification to reload table view.